# When running a Perl script from Python and writing the output to a file, why is the file empty?

Tags: python, linux, perl

I have the following Perl script that takes an Ethernet interface name and transfer rate as parameters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$prevRXpacks = 0;
$prevTXpacks = 0;
$prevRXbytes = 0;
$prevTXbytes = 0;
$recentRXpacks = 0;
$recentTXpacks = 0;
$recentRXbytes = 0;
$recentTXbytes = 0;
$time_wait_default = 2;
$time_run_default = 0;
$prev = 0;
$overflow = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
$k = 1000;
$m = $k * $k;
$format = "";
$format_value = 1;
$hdr_format = "Bytes/s";

if ( defined ($ARGV[0]) && ($ARGV[0] eq "--help") ) {
    print "Usage: $0 <device> [-r runtime] [-d delaytime]\n";
    print " -r     time to run traffic monitor in seconds (default = 0 <- forever)\n";
    print " -d     delay between two records in seconds (default = $time_wait_default)\n";
    print " -k, -K    print transfer rate in kbits/s or KBytes/s\n";
    print " -m, -M    print transfer rate in mbits/s or MBytes/s\n";
    die "\n";
}

open (OUT, "/dev/null");
select (OUT);
if ( !defined($ARGV[0]) || !`/sbin/ifconfig $ARGV[0]` ) {
    close (OUT);
    select (STDOUT);
    die "Usage $0 <device> [-r runtime] [-d delaytime] [-kmKM].\nTry --help for more.\n";
}
close (OUT);
select (STDOUT);

$time_wait = $time_wait_default;
$time_run = $time_run_default;

$i = 1;

while ( defined ($ARGV[$i]) ) {
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-d") {
        $time_wait = $ARGV[++$i] || $time_wait_default;
    }
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-r") {
        $time_run = $ARGV[++$i] || $time_run_default;
    }
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-K") {
        $format = $hdr_format = "KBytes/s";
        $format_value = $k;
    }
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-k") {
        $format = $hdr_format = "Kbits/s";
        $format_value = $k/8;
    }
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-M")  {
        $format = $hdr_format = "MBytes/s";
        $format_value = $m;
    }
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-m") {
        $format = $hdr_format = "Mbits/s";
        $format_value = $m/8;
    }

    $i++;
}

print "Traffic monitoring...\n";

# main loop
$time_loop = $time_run + time();

while ( time() < $time_loop || !$time_run ) {
    $recent = time();
    foreach $_ (`/sbin/ifconfig $ARGV[0]`) {
        if (/RX.*packets/) {
            ($blabla1, $blabla2, $blabla3) = split(/\s+/);
            ($blabla1, $recentRXpacks, $blabla2) = split(/:/, $blabla3);
        }
        if (/TX.*packets/) {
            ($blabla1, $blabla2, $blabla3) = split(/\s+/);
            ($blabla1, $recentTXpacks, $blabla2) = split(/:/, $blabla3);
        }
        if (/RX.*bytes/) {
            ($blabla1, $blabla2, $blabla3) = split(/:/);
            ($recentRXbytes) = split(/ /, $blabla2);
            ($recentTXbytes) = split(/ /, $blabla3);
        }
    }

    if ( ($recent > $prev) && $prev) {
        $interval = $recent - $prev;
#       $interval = $time_wait;

        $RXpacks = round (rate ($prevRXpacks, $recentRXpacks, $interval));
        $TXpacks = round (rate ($prevTXpacks, $recentTXpacks, $interval));
        $RXbytes = round (rate ($prevRXbytes, $recentRXbytes, $interval)/$format_value);
        $TXbytes = round (rate ($prevTXbytes, $recentTXbytes, $interval)/$format_value);

        write;
    }

    $prev = $recent;
    $prevRXpacks = $recentRXpacks;
    $prevTXpacks = $recentTXpacks;
    $prevRXbytes = $recentRXbytes;
    $prevTXbytes = $recentTXbytes;

    $time_delay = $time_wait + time();
    while (time() < $time_delay) {}
}

format STDOUT_TOP =
RX [packets/s]    TX [packets/s]    RX [@<<<<<<<]        TX [@<<<<<<<]
                   $hdr_format,           $hdr_format
.

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$RXpacks,    $TXpacks,    $RXbytes." ".$format,    $TXbytes." ".$format
.

sub rate {
    my ($prev, $recent);
    ($prev, $recent, $interval) = @_;
    if (($recent = $recent - $prev) <0) {
        $recent += $overflow;
    }
    return $recent/$interval;
}

sub round {
    my ($mod, $result);
    $result = int ($_[0]);
    $mod = ($_[0] - $result) ;
    if ( $mod >= 0.5) {
        $result++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I tried to run the above script from Python and write the output to a file using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import time

command = ["perl", "/root/Desktop/myethtraffic.pl", "eth0", "M"]

dir_name = "/root/Desktop/"

logfile = open("/root/Desktop/aa1a.txt", 'w')

proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
for line in proc.stderr:
        logfile.write(line)
```

The file is created but is empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Comment: ya if i do ./myethtraffic eth0 M it works

Answer (score 1):

Ref the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor I think you need to explicitly specify `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` when you call `POpen`, otherwise the subprocesses stderr will be hooked up to your main programs stderr.

Try this:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Test:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import time

command = ["perl", "-e", "warn 'abc'"]

logfile = open("a.log", 'w')

proc=subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stderr:
        logfile.write(line)
```

Edit: Does your perl process actually write to stderr, or to stdout?

Comment: With `stdout=subprocess.pipe` and then reading `proc.stdout`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the file descriptor to `Popen` and the program will write straight to the file and you don't need to read the pipes. I was a bit confused because you are trying to read `stderr` not `stdout`, so wrote an example that writes both pipes to one file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
import time

command = ["perl","/root/Desktop/myethtraffic.pl", "eth0", "M"]

dir_name = "/root/Desktop/"

logfile = open("/root/Desktop/aa1a.txt", 'w')

proc=subprocess.Popen(command, 
    stdout=open("/root/Desktop/aa1a.txt", 'w'), 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.wait()
```

Comment: i tryed ur solution but the problem is if i send ctrl+c to my python script that dosent stop it i mean the perl script continues running then i have to kill it by finding the pid of the perl script using the "top" command in linux and giving pid to "kill" command, any suggesstion

Comment: You can fix it in the child perl script by catching `SIGHUP` and exiting. In the python parent, you could create a global list that has processes you want to kill. Add / remove Popens as the program runs and implement an `atexit` hook that kills anything in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `perl` isn't in your path.
Pass the full path to `perl` instead of the string "perl", e.g

```
command = ["/usr/bin/perl", ...]
```

Another option is to run the command using a shell, to simulate how it would run when executed directly from the command line.

```
subprocess.Popen("/root/Desktop/myethtraffic.pl eth0 M", ..., shell=True)
```

Comment: The perl command executes, the problem is getting the results to a file.